# How to dynamically create a List in a function in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, dynamic-allocation

I have a code written in c. I have a pointer to int in main and I pass it to a function. This function allocates memory and populates the array, then it returns. Basically looks like this:

```
main()
{
  int* array;
  function(&array);
}

void function(int** array)
{
  int size = 25;
  *array = malloc(size);
  (*array)[0] = 42;
}
```

Size is not known in main. How do I do this in C#? I tried with List but I cannot make it work. I have tried both List and ref List, and they both give Index was out of range.

EDIT:

This works fine

```
class Program
{
    static void function(List<int> array)
    {
        array.Add(42);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> array = new List<int>();
        function(array);
    }
}
```

And this one too

```
class Program
{
    static void function(out int[] array)
    {
        array = new int[25];
        array[0] = 42;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] array;
        function(out array);
    }
}
```

But the following throws an exception

```
class Program
{
    static void function(out List<int> array)
    {
        array = new List<int>(25);
        array[0] = 42;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> array;
        function(out array);
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I tried with List but I cannot make it work."_ Where's your attempt?

Comment: What was the error thrown with `list`, because I don't see/forsee any problem with List being used the same/similar way.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: An array is not a list. You haven't made clear whether you want a list or an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) has the [ref](https://www.dotnetperls.com/ref) keyword for this purpose. Although it is not required in this case because an array is a reference type anyway it is a good idea nevertheless because it conveys the design intent. Better yet to use the **out** keyword as the argument to the function doesn't need to be initialized before the call.

Try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] a;
        function(out a);
        Debug.WriteLine(a.Length);
    }

    public static void function(out int[] array)
    {
        array=new int[25];
        array[0]=42;
    }
}
```

**Edit 1** - Alternate way with returning an array

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] a = CreateArray();
        Debug.WriteLine(a.Length);
    }

    public static int[] CreateArray() 
    {
        int[] array=new int[25];
        array[0]=42;
        return array;
    }
}
```

**Edit 2** - Example with two **out** parameters

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] akw, zuk;
        function(out akw, out zuk);
        Debug.WriteLine(akw.Length);
        Debug.WriteLine(zuk.Length);
    }

    public static void function(out int[] A, out int[] B) 
    {
        A=new int[25];
        B=new int[15];
        A[0]=42;
        B[0]=21;
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be better to just return the array as the return value, instead of as an out parameter.

Comment: I was sticking to the _OP_ code, but yes, I would have done it with a function return. I edited the code to show this.

Comment: I have read the comments, gonna try them now. But first, returning the array is not an option because I may want to pass at least two arrays to the function. I didn't want to crowd the pseudo-ish code with extra details.

Comment: I added an example with two array arguments. The next C# will allow multiple return values from a function using `Tuples`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Class Demo
{


 static void main (string[] args)
 {
    var result=Add();
    Console.WriteLine(result[0]);
 }

  static List<int> Add ()
  {
    var listOfints= new List<int>();
    listOfints.Add(42); //either this or declare an array of integers and get it initialized by reading the user value and pass the same as param here to initialize and return the array
    return listOfints;
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't like that `_listOfints` is a field that is initialized in the `Add()` method. I think it is bad coding. Also it does not have the same intent as in _OP_ the array is local to `main()`.

Comment: Sure - something I came up with as quickly as possible to help, hence the alternate i suggested on my comments to declare a local variable and return the same. `Out` would be the most closest thing possible, however thought returning something locally would be a better alternative

Comment: @ja72 Alright, as per your comment, which I don't deny I have altered my code. Again that was something that I came up with quickly to get it started.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason that you're having problems assigning value [0] to a c# list is that unless you create a List<> collection with a predefined start size it will be empty.  Thus entry [0] is null and can't be set.

If you want to directly access element 0, use this:

```
  void function(out List<int> list)
  {
     list = new List<int>(25);
     list[0] = 42;
  }
```

If instead you don't need to / know the initial allocation size of the List, use this: (recommended IMHO)

```
  void function(out List<int> list)
  {
     list = new List<int>();
     list.Add(42);
  }
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Another way (Although it's recommended to use a `List<int>`)

Replace `int *` with `out int[]`

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] array;
        function(out array);
        Console.WriteLine(array[0]);
    }

    static void function(out int[] array)
    {
        int size = 25;
        array = new int[size];
        array[0] = 42;
    }
}
```

Output

```
42
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above c# uses references. Pointers are supported but you would need to write unmanaged code..
 More info about references here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx

A sample is below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace alistnamespace
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> my_list=new List<int>();
            functionaddtolist(ref my_list);
            for(int i=0;i<my_list.Count;i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("List item " + i.ToString() + "=" + my_list[i]);
            }
        }

        static void functionaddtolist(ref List<int> mylist_ref)
        {
            mylist_ref.Add(42);             //Add one element

        }
    }
}
```